# Error: Resources exceeded during query execution

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running the following query on a table with 100M+ records and getting "resource exceeded" error. Any way to work around it? Thanks.

```
SELECT  a_date, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN didX_today is FALSE THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY didX_ever ORDER EACH BY a_date ASC) as times_didX
FROM table
```

Comment: We'd need more information about your use case and your data schema  to provide a better way to do that.... for now, it looks like your request is okay, but a ressource exceeded error could be anything. Could you add the full error to your question, as well as a bit more context? :)